# Map to show property location LWC

Tags: salesforcedx

I have an org with a custom object called Property.  I wish to put a LWC map on the Property record page that shows the location of the Property on the map.  Haven't quite been able to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have created a similar component using lightning, you can refer: https://newstechnologystuff.com/2018/10/22/lightningmap-show-data-on-google-map/

Answer (score 2):

There is already a component available `lightning-map`, which you can refer

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleMapSingleMarker extends LightningElement {
    mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: { //just pass property location here
                Street: '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW',
                City: 'Washington',
                State: 'DC',
            },

            title: 'The White House',
            description:
                'Landmark, historic home & office of the United States president, with tours for visitors.',
        },
    ];
}
```

component:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Single Marker</h1>
        <p class="slds-text-body_regular">A single marker is displayed on the map. Map is centered on that marker and zoom is calculated automatically.</p>
    </div>
    <lightning-map
        map-markers={mapMarkers}
    ></lightning-map>
</template>
```

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/example

Comment: Thank you Tushar.  The code you wrote above seems like something that will work if the Property address is static.  However, I am looking to set this up so that whatever Property object you pull up (222 State St., 333 Hudson St., etc.), it will indicate that particular property on the map.  I tried using your code on your web site under "Iterate Map in Lightning Web Component," but haven't had luck with that.  For one thing, when I wrote the LwcMapIterationController class in IntelliJ, it said that the controller class was never used.

Comment: @robertlangedc I suggest you to add your code. As the above solution will work on dynamic address as well.